# Using master password with Firefox doesn't load CSS

Tags: windows-7, firefox

If I have like 10 tabs open and I close the browser, the next time I open Firefox I have to enter the master password to continue (which I don't mind).  But after entering the password and restoring the session for the 10 tabs, none of the CSS is loaded even though everything else does.  I'm using NoScript, Adblock Plus, Gmail manager, and Google Reader add-ons.

Anyone know why the CSS doesn't load? I have to refresh each tab again to reload the CSS.

Comment: What version of FF? I've had a similar issue at 3.6, but it has been solved since then.

Comment: I'm using version 7.0